# Reading pixel from byte array in Android Native function

Tags: android, arrays, image-processing, android-ndk, pixel

Im tryin to read pixel data for every frame I get from camera. I want to use native code for performance. I pass frame.image, which is byte array, to native func and expected to get pixels(int array). Then I set those pixels to bitmap.

Java Side:

```
if (bitmap == null) {
    int bitmapHeight = frame.size.height;
    int bitmapWidth = frame.size.width;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    pixel = new int[bitmapWidth * bitmapHeight];}

imageProcessing(frame.size.width, frame.size.height, frame.image, pixel);
bitmap.setPixels(pixel, 0, frame.size.width, 0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```

NDK Side: I have very little knowledge on this side. Currently returns zero int array

```
Java_com_app_myapp_ui_camera_CameraFragment_imageProcessing(
    JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,
    jint width, jint height,
    jbyteArray NV21FrameData, jintArray outPixels)
{
jbyte * pNV21FrameData = env->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData, 0);
jint * poutPixels = env->GetIntArrayElements(outPixels, 0);


//Mat mGray(height, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)pNV21FrameData);
//Mat mResult(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)poutPixels);

env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData, pNV21FrameData, 0);
env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(outPixels, poutPixels, 0);
return true;
}
```

So how can I fill pixel in imageProecessing func?

Comment: By writing to `poutPixels`.

Comment: better use `copyPixelsFromBuffer` the dosc say:  *"The data in the buffer is not changed in any way (unlike setPixels(), which converts from unpremultipled 32bit to whatever the bitmap's native format is"* or better yet `AndroidBitmap_*` native functions declared in `android/bitmap.h` header

Comment: @Michael shouldn't it be writing on outPixels. Also a little explanation please. I'm lost

Comment: @pskink all funcs. in `bitmap.h` gets bitmap but Im creating actual bitmap after native part.

Comment: yes, they need `Bitmap` as a parameter, so whats wrong with it?

Comment: @pskink native func. receives `frame.image` and its byte array not bitmap

Comment: so what do you need `bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap` for?

Comment: @pskink my logic is this: Create a empty bitmap with size of frame, then in native part acquire the pixel info from byte array, then fill bitmap with those pixels

Comment: so this is what `AndroidBitmap_*` methods are doing

Comment: @pskink in `bitmap.h`all I can see is `AndroidBitmap_getInfo()`, `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels()`, `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels()` so how do I use them to create bitmap from byte array?

Comment: `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels`, in java you do `bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap` and then you are passing this `bitmap` to `AndroidBitmap_*` methods